# Downloading old QGIS releases for Mac?

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I've encountered some problems running my old 1.8 project in 2.0. I would like to reinstall QGIS 1.8 but seems that there are no more 1.8 installer  in [KingChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis). In QGIS "all releases" there isn't.

Where I can find the old release for Mac user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link only is not sufficient: all the archives of KyngChaos software and Frameworks are in [Kyngchaos: Unix Port Download Archive](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive#qgis).

But, if you want to have the 2 versions, you need to rename temporarily the installed version of QGIS.app into QGIS2.0.app, for example, otherwise it will be replaced by the 1.8 version. You can use them at the same time

Answer (score 3):

Please check out http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/qgis/QGIS-1.8.0-2.dmg to download.